# Yesterday, I went to Paris

Tags: tense, past-tense

> Yesterday, I went to Paris

and

> I have been to Paris yesterday.

Which one is the most suitable and please explain the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: "I have been to Paris yesterday" would almost never be used.  "Yesterday, I went to Paris" is appropriate for most contexts.

Comment: If i ask a student who was absent yesterday in the class like; where have you been? will it indicate his/her yesterday absence properly?

Comment: There, *Where had you been to?* works!

Comment: @MaulikV: "Where had you been to?" sounds... awkward at best. "Where **have** you been to?" can work (for asking about a person's life experiences), but the version with *had* plus *to* just doesn't sound right.

Comment: The most common expression for that situation would be "Where were you yesterday?".

Comment: @Martha Hey, do you know *Brendan Rodgers [had been to New York](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/09/sports/baseball/at-50-major-league-draft-has-sharpened-its-focus.html?_r=0) once before this month*

Comment: @MaulikV: yeah, so? The existence of a sentence where "had been to" is correct has absolutely no bearing on the fact that "Where had you been to?" is **not** correct.

Comment: What problem do you think is there? The preposition? What about *'Where had you been?'* @Martha

Answer (score 1):

We don't use present perfect (e.g. have been to) with definite past time expression like yesterday, last week, three years ago, in 2001.

If you want to mean 'you went to Paris and came back' you say 'you've been to Paris' and by this sentence you mean you have the experience of going to Paris. You don't want to say when you did it. You just did something in the past and the time doesn't matter or you can't remember. If you want to say exactly when you did it, use simple past i.e. 'You went to paris yesterday'

(Comment: Laila it's a good idea to explain more when you post a question. Say atleast what you want to say. Give a context. If your question seems general or others feel you haven't tried enough to find the answer somewhere else they down-vote you.)

Answer (score 1):

"I have been to Paris" means that at some unspecified point in the past, you visited Paris. If you want to specify a particular time for the visit, you can't just tack it onto this sort of construction. Instead, you'd use a simple past tense:

> I went to Paris yesterday.

This is true even if you're giving this in answer to a question like "Where have you been?" I know that question *sounds* like it's asking something like "What cities have you been to on your travels?", but what it's actually asking (most of the time) is "Why weren't you here earlier? What excuse do you have?" (OK, so sometimes it's less exasperated, more like "I noticed you weren't here earlier. Where were you?", but still, it's asking for your immediately-prior actions, not your life experience.)